# Отнять один столбец от другого с одной строки

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Здраствуйте, проблема в следующем:
У меня есть база данных в mysql, где есть список автомобилей с 2 столбцами - price и pay.
Нужно чтобы price вычитался от pay в каждой строке для каждого автомобиля отдельно. Значения в price разные.

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
$sum = $ulist['price'];
$query  = "UPDATE cars SET pay = pay - $sum";
```

но от pay рассчитывается последние значение price последнего автомобиля.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: *Нужно чтобы price вычитался от pay в каждой строке для каждого автомобиля отдельно.* Не нужно Вам этого. Текущий актуальный баланс элементарно считается простейшим запросом. А вот корректировка данных способна (и скорее всего приведёт) к проблемам. Например, код с вычитанием может быть выполнен дважды (по ошибке или даже злонамеренно) - и этот факт даже не удастся определить, пока когда-нибудь не выяснится, что не сходится баланс (и даже в этот момент - не получится выяснить, когда и при каких обстоятельствах вычитание было произведено дважды).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это решается довольно просто через sql. Следующий код вернёт вам вычтенное значение для каждой строки, кроме последней.

```
SELECT id, pay - price AS result FROM cars WHERE id != (SELECT MAX(id) FROM cars)
```

Ну и обновить БД можно просто расширив ваш update:

```
UPDATE cars SET pay = pay - $sum WHERE id != (SELECT a.id FROM (select MAX(id) AS id FROM cars) AS a)
```

Тут пришлось вложить select в select иначе sql не понимает запроса и выдаёт ошибку

> Ошибка SQL (1093): You can't specify target table 'cars' for update in
> FROM clause

**Обновление:**
Когда вы привели полный код, стало понятно почему так произошло. У вас этот запрос был в цикле, каждую итерацию он обновлял все данные на основании введённого значения. Надо либо ещё условие добавить  `AND id = $ulist['id']`, либо можно сделать проще не получая предварительно цену и не проходясь циклом:

```
$query  = "UPDATE cars SET pay = pay - price WHERE id != (SELECT a.id FROM (select MAX(id) AS id FROM cars) AS a)";
$q = mysqli_query($as, $query);
```

Вот так должно сработать и вычесть прайс из пэй для всех записей, кроме последней. Её трогать не стал тк у Вас

> от pay рассчитывается последние значение price последнего автомобиля.

Comment: Может я не туда вставил строчки ваши, но у меня вычитывает от последнего добавленного id, а последний id не вычитываеться

Comment: @МаксимВінтоняк А, даже так? Ну, полного кода, что вы привели стало понятно, что можно просто 1 запросом всё сделать. Обновил ответ

Comment: Работает, спасибо огромное, но не последнего автомобиля, а всех. Можно как то решить, чтобы от всех машин вычеслялось price от pay, просто сейчас последняя не вычесляеться

Comment: @МаксимВінтоняк Просто уберите всю часть where и у вас для всех записей сработает

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

Это мой исходный код

```
<?php
$resultul = mysqli_query($as,"SELECT * FROM `cars`");           
while ($ulist = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultul))

$sum = $ulist['price'];
{   
    
    $query  = "UPDATE cars SET pay = pay - $sum";
    $q = mysqli_query($as, $query);
    
header('location: ..\index.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).